400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port nginx
I am also getting same issue can anyone help me to solve this ?
    server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name www.example.com www1.example.com;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }


400 means someone tries to access your server with plain http using https port. Something like http://example.com:443/. Sometimes it's just wild internet so you could ignore it. Sometimes it's your own other server that was configured incorrectly. Check the IP of request and proceed accordingly
